# Select2 multi-select with no closeOnSelect overlaps results on top of selected tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

**Problem:**

When I have a `select2()` with `closeOnSelect =false,` the results list overlaps the selected values when the no of selected values cause the values to wrap around.

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>...
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#e1").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
})
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/dsg2t7y2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not much cleaner than Sajjan's answer. You could call a close and open in the change event of the select. This causes the box to be redrawn on every selection without the need of knowing what class names select2 happens to be using this version (in case it changes).

```
var select = $("#e1").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
}).on("change", function(e){
  select.select2("close");
  select.select2("open");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsg2t7y2/1/

This has the advantage of using the same methods select2 would normally use to position the dropdown. So if you have any on the page which do close on select, the look will be consistent.

Sidenote: as annoying as it is, both with and without this the scroller returns to the top after every selection. *shudders* it kinda kills me inside

Comment: After looking it doesn't appear that select2 has a means to redraw, without a close and open. Might be something to request on their github: https://github.com/select2/select2/

Comment: Fair enough, your code is cleaner and not dependent on the CSS class names unlike my answer. I will accept it, I wish select2 handled it on their side though as this is a bug. Oh well, maybe in future releases! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**A Solution:**

I found one way of solving it, would welcome other suggestions.

Added an event handler for the `open` and select events which repositions the results span every time.

```
$("#e1").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
}).on('select2:select select2:open', function(evt) {
  var $container = $(this).data("select2").$container.find(".select2-selection__rendered");
  var $results = $(".select2-dropdown--below");
  $results.position({
    my: "top",
    at: "bottom",
    of: $container
  });  
});;
```

**Working Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/hvsvcc5r/

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Your example doesn't cover deselecting items. Small change to event handler though. You can just use `change`